# Get specific product attribute values for a specific product category in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I  have already managed to get all the color attributes with this code:

```
$color_terms = get_terms(
        array(
        'taxonmy'=>'pa_color'
    ));
```

This works fine for Shop page and returns all the colors  but how can I limit it to a certain category? Lets say in a category named "Shirts" I have only 2 colors and I want to only show those 2 colors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try the following custom function that use a unique light SQL query:

```
function get_attribute_terms_in_product_cat( $category_term_name, $attribute_taxonomy ){
    global $wpdb;

    $terms = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT DISTINCT t.*
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}terms as t
        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy as tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships as tr ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
        WHERE tt.taxonomy LIKE '$attribute_taxonomy'
        AND tr.object_id IN ( SELECT DISTINCT tr2.object_id
            FROM {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships as tr2
            JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy as tt2 ON tt2.term_taxonomy_id = tr2.term_taxonomy_id
            JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms as t2 ON tt2.term_id = t2.term_id
            WHERE tt2.taxonomy LIKE 'product_cat' AND t2.name = '$category_term_name'
        )" );

    return $terms;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**USAGE**:

```
// Get the "pa_color" attribute terms for product category "Shirts"
$terms = get_attribute_terms_in_product_cat( "Shirts", "pa_color" );
```

Here **"Shirts"** is a product category term name and **"pa_color"** the product attribute taxonomy…

You will get an array of product attribute values (term object) containing:

- the term ID *(key `term_id`)*
- the term name *(key `name`)*
- the term slug *(key `slug`)*

You can use a foreach loop to access each term object:

```
// Get the "pa_color" attribute terms for product category "Shirts"
$terms = get_attribute_terms_in_product_cat( "Shirts", "pa_color" );

// Loop through each term
foreach( $terms as $term ){
    $term_id   = $term->term_id;
    $term_name = $term->name;
    $term_slug = $term->slug;
}
```

Comment: Great work. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes. I have already upvoted.